# The sequence $a_n=\frac{n^2}{n^3+200},n\in N$ has the $7$ th term as largest term.Why?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> The function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^3+200}$ attains does not attain local maxima at >$x=7$ but the sequence $a_n=\frac{n^2}{n^3+200},n\in N$ has the $7$ th term as >largest term.Why?

---

$$f'(x)=\frac{(x^3+200)2x-x^2(3x^2)}{(x^3+200)^2}=0$$ gives $$\frac{400x-x^4}{(x^3+200)^2}=0$$
$$x=0,(400)^{1/3}$$
So the points of extremum are $x=0,(400)^{1/3}$.
But the sequence $a_n=\frac{n^2}{n^3+200},n\in N$ looks like this function and this sequence attains its maximum value at $n=7$.

---

My question is:Is there a method to find the largest value and the smallest value of a sequence and the number at which this occurs.

Comment: That is because $\lfloor{400^\frac{1}{3}}\rfloor = 7$.

Comment: May be. Not universal method, but usable for your example and another examples.
Function $a_{n}=\frac{n^{2}}{n^{3}+300} $ is a discrete equivalent of function $ f(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{x^{3}+300} $, which is increasing at (1,7) and decreasing at (8, inf). So, 7 or 8 is minimum of sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because $\lfloor{400^\frac{1}{3}}\rfloor = 7$ and $\lceil{400^\frac{1}{3}}\rceil = 8$.

Hence one of these values should be the maximum in the case of a numeric sequence in the case of a function that is *concave or convex in the interval between the two integers*.

Which one it will be will depend on the function describing the sequence.

Comment: Should $7$ or $8$ be the point of maxima,then?

Comment: It depends on the function. It may not be defined at 7 and 8, for example. Or if the function dips after 7, has a peak and then dips again before 8, we will not be able to determine the number at which the extremum occurs. Hence the extra text added above about it being concave or convex in the interval between the two integers.

Comment: It is important that $f$ is *unimodal*, i.e., increasing for $x<400^{1/3}$ and decreasing for $x>400^{1/3}$. Only then your argument works.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I have mentioned that the function should be concave or convex between the two integers. Doesn't that mean it's unimodal?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and define $a_n=f(n)$ for $n\in \Bbb N$. Assume $n_0>1$ and $f(n_0)>f(n)$ for all $n\ne n_0$. Then $f$ has a local maximum in the interval $(n_0-1,n_0+1)$.
This follows because the continuous function $f$ assumes a maximum on the compact interval $[n_0-1,n_0+1]$ and by assumption, this maximum cannot occur at the two boundary points.

---

The converse need not hold: It may happen that $f$ has a strict global maximum in the interval $(7,8)$, say, but $a_n$ has no maximum at all. For example, we could make $a_n=-\frac1n$, while $f(x)$ is not $\frac1x$ throughout, but instead has a "bump" in $(7,8)$.